# Component Initialization - Runtime vs. Designtime

Tags: delphi, custom-component

I have a series of visual compound components that I'm building, which use similar / common "connect" methods, which fire up there internal tables, etc.

I am automating some of the connection stuff to connect automatically at runtime.  How do I tell, at the component level, if the current state is runtime or designtime?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you want to check if the `csDesigning` flag is present in the component's `ComponentState` property:

```
if csDesigning in ComponentState then
  // designtime
else
  // not designtime
```

Comment: This is incorrect ; compiled exe with the DEBUG flag still have csDesigning.